# How to find get the variable name having largest value in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Consider a table with Names in 'A' and their Marks in 'B'. I need to find the Name with maximum marks and use this name as a result of another Condition.

[image: Please refer here]

In this Sheet, My Maximum value is "SZ04", I need this as the result of Max function and not the value(6) itself.

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [ask]. It looks like you'll need the MAX, MATCH and INDEX formulae.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance dude. I used MAX function and stored the maximum value in a Variable. I thought to take the declared variable name as a String value and use in the program further. But still can't find how to return the Variable name with maximum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *INDEX()*, *MATCH()*, and *MAX()* functions:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))
```

[image]

So in *VBA*:

```
Sub WhatsInaName()
    Dim strng As String

    strng = Evaluate("INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))")
    MsgBox strng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something like that

```
Sub Test()
Dim x

x = Application.Match(Application.Max(Columns(2)), Columns(2), 0)

If Not IsError(x) Then
    MsgBox Cells(x, 1).Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you dude. I will try this for my solution and will post you an update.